# Material UI DataGrid - onClick of checkbox event?

Tags: material-ui

I have a DataGrid that displays a list of Todos. The user can edit the Todo, as well as use the included checkbox to mark it off their list.

```react
<DataGrid
  checkboxSelection
  columnBuffer={0}
  disableColumnMenu
  disableColumnSelector
  disableDensitySelector
  disableSelectionOnClick
  hideFooterPagination
  hideFooter
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  onCellEditCommit={params => handleUpdate(params)}
  selectionModel={selectionModel}
  onSelectionModelChange={(model: GridSelectionModel) =>
    setSelectionModel(model)
  }
/>
```

Everything works fine *except* for the checkbox. You can see that I am passing the `disableSelectionOnClick` prop, because I am only wanting the checkbox to toggle on click of the checkbox, rather than the entire row. I am having issues finding any sort of click event for the checkboxes though, which seems odd to me. I am upgraded to the latest version with `"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.35"`.

Anyone have an idea as to how to allow for a checkbox event?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving. It's not perfect (doesn't have a Select All checkbox now), but it works for now.

```jsx
const columns: GridColumns = [
  {
    field: 'completed',
    headerName: '',
    editable: false,
    width: 45,
    sortable: false,
    hideSortIcons: true,
    headerClassName: 'checkbox-column',
    renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={selectionModel.includes(params.id) || false}
        disableRipple
        disableFocusRipple
        onClick={() => handleToggleCompleted(params)}
      />
    ),
  },
  { field: 'title', headerName: 'Title', width: 425, editable: true },
  {
    field: 'delete',
    headerName: '',
    editable: false,
    width: 45,
    sortable: false,
    headerClassName: 'delete-item-column',
    hideSortIcons: true,
    renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => {
      return (
        <IconButton
          className="delete-btn"
          edge="end"
          aria-label="comments"
          disableRipple
          disableFocusRipple
          onClick={() => handleDelete(params)}>
          <DeleteIcon className="delete" color="inherit" />
        </IconButton>
      );
    },
  },
];

return (
  <DataGrid
    columnBuffer={0}
    disableColumnMenu
    disableColumnSelector
    disableDensitySelector
    disableSelectionOnClick
    hideFooterPagination
    hideFooter
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    onCellEditCommit={params => handleUpdate(params)}
  />
)
```