# Material-UI DataGrid - no checkbox onClick event?

Tags: material-ui

I'm resurrecting a question I'd asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614959/material-ui-datagrid-onclick-of-checkbox-event). I thought I'd come up with a good solution, but I'm wanting to find a more optimal solution. I want to enable the `checkboxSelection` prop so that each line has a checkbox, plus the Check All checkbox in the header, and on click of each of those I need to run an `update` function.

The issue I'm running in to however, is that there doesn't seem to be any sort of click handler for these checkboxes?

```jsx
    const columns: GridColumns = [
      // {
      //   field: 'completed',
      //   headerName: '',
      //   editable: false,
      //   width: 45,
      //   sortable: false,
      //   hideSortIcons: true,
      //   headerClassName: 'checkbox-column',
      //   renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => (
      //     <Checkbox
      //       checked={selectionModel.includes(params.id) || false}
      //       disableRipple
      //       disableFocusRipple
      //       onClick={() => handleToggleCompleted(params)}
      //     />
      //   ),
      // },
      { field: 'title', headerName: 'Title', width: 280, editable: true },
      {
        field: 'quantity',
        headerName: 'Quantity',
        type: 'number',
        editable: true,
        width: 150,
      },
      {
        field: 'delete',
        headerName: '',
        editable: false,
        width: 45,
        sortable: false,
        headerClassName: 'delete-item-column',
        hideSortIcons: true,
        renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => {
          return (
            <IconButton
              className="delete-btn"
              edge="end"
              aria-label="comments"
              disableRipple
              disableFocusRipple
              onClick={() => handleDelete(params)}>
              <DeleteIcon className="delete" color="inherit" />
            </IconButton>
          );
        },
      },
    ];

    <DataGrid
      checkboxSelection
      columnBuffer={0}
      disableColumnMenu
      disableColumnSelector
      disableDensitySelector
      disableSelectionOnClick
      hideFooterPagination
      hideFooter
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      onCellEditCommit={params => handleUpdate(params)}
    />
```

So if I had the `checkboxSelection` prop, how can I hook in to the onClick event for that specific checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out a good solution!

I stumbled across the `renderHeader` option for defining columns, which allows me to define the onClick function.

```jsx
  const columns: GridColumns = [
    {
      field: 'completed',
      editable: false,
      width: 45,
      sortable: false,
      hideSortIcons: true,
      headerClassName: 'checkbox-column',
      renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={selectionModel.includes(params.id) || false}
          disableRipple
          disableFocusRipple
          onClick={() => handleToggleCompleted(params)}
        />
      ),
      renderHeader: () => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={rows.every(r => r.completed) || false}
          disableRipple
          disableFocusRipple
          onChange={e => handleToggleAllCompleted(e.target.checked)}
          style={{ paddingLeft: '4px' }}
        />
      ),
    },
    { field: 'title', headerName: 'Title', width: 425, editable: true },
    {
      field: 'delete',
      headerName: '',
      editable: false,
      width: 45,
      sortable: false,
      headerClassName: 'delete-item-column',
      hideSortIcons: true,
      renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => {
        return (
          <IconButton
            className="delete-btn"
            edge="end"
            aria-label="comments"
            disableRipple
            disableFocusRipple
            onClick={() => handleDelete(params)}>
            <DeleteIcon className="delete" color="inherit" />
          </IconButton>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  <DataGrid
    columnBuffer={0}
    disableColumnMenu
    disableColumnSelector
    disableDensitySelector
    disableSelectionOnClick
    hideFooterPagination
    hideFooter
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    onCellEditCommit={params => handleUpdate(params)}
  />
```

Comment: Hi @j.jackson Can you please share a codesandbox or codepen link of your code